# transform dates into other format?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have many event dates that are read out as `20131212`  or `20100125` or it could be any date a user has submitted as an event (structure is **yyyymmdd**)

now i have made a function that displays all events that month. But the date gets read out as `20131212`

How can I replace the `20131212`  or whatever date that it is transfomed into the format 
**`2013/12/12`** The events are stored in a txt file

and this for all structures like this
Is that possible?

CODE

```
   <link href="plugins/calender/calendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="plugins/calender/calendar.full.js"></script>
<div class="style1">
<div class="calendar" data-color="<?php echo $calendarcolor ?>">
<?php include('admin/events/events.txt') ?>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<H3>Aankomende events</H3>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    //how much items per page to show
    var show_per_page = 1; 
    //getting the amount of elements inside content div
    var number_of_items = $('#content').children().size();
    //calculate the number of pages we are going to have
    var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(number_of_items/show_per_page);

    //set the value of our hidden input fields
    $('#current_page').val(0);
    $('#show_per_page').val(show_per_page);

    //now when we got all we need for the navigation let's make it '

    /* 
    what are we going to have in the navigation?
        - link to previous page
        - links to specific pages
        - link to next page
    */
    var navigation_html = '<a class="previous_link" href="javascript:previous();">Vorige</a>';
    var current_link = 0;
    while(number_of_pages > current_link){
        navigation_html += '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(' + current_link +')" longdesc="' + current_link +'">'+ (current_link + 1) +'</a>';
        current_link++;
    }
    navigation_html += '<a class="next_link" href="javascript:next();">Volgende</a>';

    $('#page_navigation').html(navigation_html);

    //add active_page class to the first page link
    $('#page_navigation .page_link:first').addClass('active_page');

    //hide all the elements inside content div
    $('#content').children().css('display', 'none');

    //and show the first n (show_per_page) elements
    $('#content').children().slice(0, show_per_page).css('display', 'block');

});

function previous(){

    new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) - 1;
    //if there is an item before the current active link run the function
    if($('.active_page').prev('.page_link').length==true){
        go_to_page(new_page);
    }

}

function next(){
    new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) + 1;
    //if there is an item after the current active link run the function
    if($('.active_page').next('.page_link').length==true){
        go_to_page(new_page);
    }

}
function go_to_page(page_num){
    //get the number of items shown per page
    var show_per_page = parseInt($('#show_per_page').val());

    //get the element number where to start the slice from
    start_from = page_num * show_per_page;

    //get the element number where to end the slice
    end_on = start_from + show_per_page;

    //hide all children elements of content div, get specific items and show them
    $('#content').children().css('display', 'none').slice(start_from, end_on).css('display', 'block');

    /*get the page link that has longdesc attribute of the current page and add active_page class to it
    and remove that class from previously active page link*/
    $('.page_link[longdesc=' + page_num +']').addClass('active_page').siblings('.active_page').removeClass('active_page');

    //update the current page input field
    $('#current_page').val(page_num);
}

</script>

<!-- the input fields that will hold the variables we will use -->
      <input type='hidden' id='current_page' />
    <input type='hidden' id='show_per_page' />


<div id='content'> 


    <?php
$file = fopen("admin/events/events.txt", "r");
while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
$line = str_replace("<div data-role='day' data-day='", "<b><u>Datum:</b></u> (yyyy/mm/dd formaat) ", $line);
$line = str_replace("'><div data-role='event' data-name='<h1>", " <br><b><u>Event:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-start='", " <br><b><u>Start:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-end='", " <br><b><u>Einde:</b></u> Tot ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-location='", " <br><b><u>Locatie:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("</h1>", " <br><b><u>Inhoud event:</b></u><br> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("'></div></div>", "", $line);
echo "<div class='event'>$line</div>"; 
}
fclose($file);

?>


</div>
<br>
<div id='page_navigation'></div>
```

Comment: Some code wouldnt be bad, i dont know why you get the dates without seperators ... in general, you can use date_format to reformat dates.

Comment: addes some code. The code is displayed in a txt file and gets read out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this. it will work for you.

```
<?php
$str = '20131212';
$date = new DateTime($str);
echo $date->format('Y/m/d');
?>
```

The output of above code is 2013/12/12

Comment: yes, but i dont now that $str wil be 20131212... it could be any date. I want to replace all 8 digit numbers in dat format

Comment: man, just use the variable where you have the date instead of `$str` and it will work...

Comment: so you can set $str = $_REQUEST['date']; where date is name of input field where any user enter the date.

Comment: u didnt read my quetsion naryl, the date isnt a variable it is a stored txt file like this: date||eventname||eventdescrition  date||eventname||eventdescrition  and so on and on. So the events are read out in explode mode. So the date isnt a varibable but just a piece of text thats included

Answer (score 0):

You meant this right ?

```
<?php
$dt = '20131212';
$ctime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $dt);
echo $ndate= $ctime->format('Y/m/d'); // "prints" 2013/12/12
```

Comment: indeed that is what i meant. And i applied that code too. But i dont know what $dt is going to be. It could be 20140416.... So is there a code that can say $dt is all 8 digit numbers?

Comment: If you don't know what it's going to be, you'll have to write some code to find out :P

Comment: `But i dont know what $dt is going to be. It could be 20140416` so what ? Above code works for that too. Just wrap the code in a function and pass your `$dt` variable to it.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$yourdate= date('Ymd');    
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($yourdate));
```

Comment: i will give this a go edit:doesnt work the actual date of today gets displayed but my 8 digits remain like they were

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work for you:

```
$new_dt=preg_replace('/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/', "\1/\2/\3", $dt);
if (strpos($new_dt, "/") === false) {
    //did nothing since the date format was wrong!
}else{
    echo "New date format: $new_dt";
}
```

Comment: ur preg_replace helpe me though to get to were i wanted to be now :) thx all, solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my problem, hopefully someone else finds this helpfull too

```
<?php
$file = fopen("admin/events/events.txt", "r");
while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
$text= $line; 
$result=htmlentities($text);
$s = $result;
preg_match_all('/data-day=\'([^\']*)\'/', $s, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $idx => $datevalue)
{
    $year = substr($datevalue, 0, 4);
    $month = substr($datevalue, 4, 2);
    $day = substr($datevalue, 6, 2);
}
$line = str_replace("<div data-role='day' data-day='$year$month$day", "<b><u>Datum:</b></u> $year-$month-$day ", $line);
$line = str_replace("'><div data-role='event' data-name='<h1>", " <br><b><u>Event:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-start='", " <br><b><u>Start:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-end='", " <br><b><u>Einde:</b></u> Tot ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-location='", " <br><b><u>Locatie:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("</h1>", " <br><b><u>Inhoud event:</b></u><br> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("'></div></div>", "", $line);
echo "<div class='event'>$line</div>"; 
}
fclose($file);

?>
```